# Scrapy For Loop not finding all index range

Tags: python, scrapy

I finished the tutorial part of building and **scraping** the quotes that Scrapy provides. I am now trying to do an actual website. The webscraper is grabbing the information I'm sending to it but it's not going down the list as I thought it would. The scrapy shell is erratic when I index through the list. when I use the shell and pass it

```
response.css('div.organic-gallery-offer-outter')[0].get()
```

It returns the 4th item on the actual website.

Here is my full code.

```
import scrapy

class HatsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hat_list"
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.alibaba.com/products/hats/CID32708.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.2d7546c4jCXuac&IndexArea=product_en',
]


custom_settings = {
    "DEPTH_LIMIT": 1,
    "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
    "AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLE": True,
    "AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY": 5.0,
}
def parse(self, response):
    for hat_list in response.css('div.organic-gallery-offer-outter'):
        yield{
            "Title": hat_list.css('p.organic-gallery-title__content::text').get(),
            "Price": hat_list.css('p.gallery-offer-price span::text').get(),
            "Min Order": hat_list.css('p.gallery-offer-minorder span::text').get(),
            "Country": hat_list.css("div.organic-gallery-offer-section__seller-tags span::text").get(),
            "Years In Business": hat_list.css("div.organic-gallery-offer-section__seller-tags span.seller-tag__year::text").get(),
            "Response Rate": hat_list.css('div.organic-gallery-offer-section__reviews span::text').get(),
            "Review Score": hat_list.css('div.organic-gallery-offer-section__reviews span.seb-supplier-review__score::text').get(),
            "Contact Link": response.urljoin(hat_list.css('div.organic-gallery-offer-section__contact a::attr(href)').get()),
        }
```

I've also tried targeting different div tags to no success. The last odd thing is there there are only 8 items in the index, anything else it say out of index. The website has 40+ items on page. Here a link to what I'm practicing on.

https://www.alibaba.com/products/hats/CID32708.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.0.0.2d7546c4jCXuac&IndexArea=product_en

Answer (score 0):

This website relies heavily on JavaScript. You either need to use a rendering engine (like [splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)), or if you already do, you need to wait a bit longer to properly load the website before you start scraping it.